# Prevent Background Repeating

Tags: html, css

How do I prevent a background from repeating? Currently it's repeated twice, but I need the background to fill the whole page without repeating (because otherwise it looks strange!). Below is my code, but I can provide a site link if needed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<img src="box.png" style="float: left;" />
<div class="navrow">
<ul>
<li class="navmenu" style="background: #6dc066;"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="navmenu" style="background: #a155e7;"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
<li class="navmenu" onclick="shakeregister();" style="background: #ffa500;">Register</li>
<li class="navmenu" style="background: #3399ff;"><a href="play.php">Login</a></li>
<li class="navmenu" style="background: #ff6666; margin-right: 0px;"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
<div style="clear: left;"></div>
</ul>
</div>
<div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
 font-family: Titillium Web, sans-serif;
 background-image: url("images/polarvillebg.png");
}

h1, h2, h3 {
 font-weight: normal;
}

.container {
 width: 70%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 2%;
}

.navrow {
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
}

.navrow li {
 display: inline-block;
}

.navrow li a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
}

.navmenu {
 height: 100px;
 width: 78px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-right: 4px;
 line-height: 100px;
 transition:height 0.5s; 
 -webkit-transition:height 0.5s; 
 box-shadow: rgb(204, 204, 204) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.navmenu:hover {
 height: 107px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Please do not deface your post after you have taken help from it. It is like cutting down a tree after taking shelter below it. Please allow the other future users to gain from the knowledge. The answerers would have put a lot of effort. Do not put their valuable time to waste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CSS rule:

```
background-size: cover;
```

will make the background image large enough so that it covers the element that it's a background to. This will also have the side effect of not repeating the background image.

---

If you're still having trouble with background repeating after that, you can use:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

to explicitly force the background not to repeat.

---

So all together, in the code you provided, the full solution would be to change your `body` rule to this:

```
body {
 font-family: Titillium Web, sans-serif;
 background-image: url("images/polarvillebg.png");
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - just what I needed!

Comment: Is it mandatory to use the background-repeat: no-repeat; or is it fine with just background-size: cover;?

Comment: @Mr.PV It should be fine with just `background-size: cover;`.

Comment: Great - I'll mark your response as the answer as soon as the time limit is up, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`background-size:cover;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

```
background-size:cover;
```

Or, in just the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) property:

```
background: url("images/polarvillebg.png") scroll no-repeat center/cover;
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobgray/LdvLbag1/)

Comment: I couldn't got this solution to work - it prevented the background from displaying.

Comment: @Mr.PV How didn't it work? check the demo

Comment: Your solution before you edited your reply wasn't working (the one in the background property) - your background-size:cover; solution worked fine.

Comment: @Mr.PV The JSFiddle uses the one from the first answer

Comment: This is its css:`background: url("http://lorempizza.com/1000/1000") scroll no-repeat center/cover;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to set the image to full screen background.

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

It will prevent from reapating, but there also exist :  background-repeat in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

just say:

```
body{
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

"no-repeat" tells the background image to stop repeating itself.
"cover" tells the image to stretch on the whole viewport (without distortion).